# Blank line left in before input

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get my output to look like this:

```
You have 6 guesses left. 
Available letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Please guess a letter:  ​ a  
Good guess: _ a_ _
```

But mine looks like this:

```
You have 1 guesses left
Available Letters:  bcdfghjklmnopqruvwxyz

Please guess a letter: m
That letter in not in my word: _ i_ _ s
```

What Python 3.X is doing is putting a blank line above when I use an input statement like this:

```
user_guess = input('Please guess a letter: ')
```

Anyway to get rid of that blank line?

Comment: `input()` doesn't put a blank line before the prompt.  The problem is obviously somewhere else in your code.  Always post a [mcve].

Comment: There shouldn't be a blank line there... please post the lines before the input (i.e. the previous prints)

Comment: Can you paste the code along with output so that, I can check the issue with the code?

Comment: Seems to be just a Sypder3 thing.  If I run the same code in a terminal it works just fine without the spaces.